# Test to see if each digit in a 9-digit integer is unique

Tags: python, if-statement

How do I write an if statement to check if each number in a 9 digit number is unique? Clearly the if statement I wrote (see the bold line) isn't working. Would appreciate any help!!

```
x_raw = int(input("Please input a 9 digit number where no digit appears twice"))
x_nexthighestnumber = x_raw + 1
x = str(x_nexthighestnumber)

number = "incorrect"

while (x_nexthighestnumber < 999999999 and number == "incorrect"):
    **if (x[0] != x[1] != x[2] != x[3] != x[4] != x[5]!= x[6] != x[7] != x[8]):**
        number = "correct"
        print (x)
    else: 
        number = "incorrect"
        x_nexthighestnumber += 1
```

Comment: Hello, your title seems to ask a different question to the main text of the question, can you please clarify?  You mean you want to find the next 9 digit number with all unique numbers higher than the one typed in?

Comment: I edited the title - By the way, if you want some fun with this, this post has minimalist answers to this problem in practically every language under the sun!!! :-) https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28359/determine-if-all-decimal-digits-are-unique  ... the leading function has just 7 characters.. wow!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just use set to find unique characters

Here is an example function

```
def x_uniq(n):
    if len(set(str(n)))<len(str(n)):
        print(n, "is not unique")
    else:
        print(n, "is unique")
```

Test:

```
x_uniq(123446789)
123446789 is not unique

x_uniq(123456789)
123456789 is unique
```

If for some reason you are allergic to the set function, or addicted to numpy, you can map the digits to a numpy array and use numpy.unique instead.  Of course, you wouldn't do it this way, I'm just having some fun:

```
import numpy as np
def x_uniq(n):
    if len(np.unique(list(map(int,str(num)))))<len(str(n)):
        print(n, "is not unique")
    else:
        print(n, "is unique")
```

ps: would be really cool to come up with an algorithm to find the number without having to cycle through the values one at a time... I'm sure there is a neat soln out there for this... The long asleep mathematician in me awakens!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
x_raw = input("Please input a 9 digit number where no digit appears twice:")
if len(x_raw) != 9:
    raise Exception('input len must be 9')

chars = set()
for x in x_raw:
    if x.isnumeric():
        chars.add(x)
    else:
        raise Exception(f'{x} is not numeric')

if len(chars) != 9:
    raise Exception('duplicates not allowed')

num = int(x_raw)
print(f'input is {num}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant create these "logic-chains" like you did: `x[0] != x[1] != x[2] != x[3] != x[4] != x[5]!= x[6] != x[7] != x[8]`
This is invalid in every programming language.
But what you can do is the following:
Replace the bold line with this:

```py
if (any(str(x).count(element) > 1 for element in str(x))):
```

But there are many way more elegant solution to this, like the other answers propose.